# Как реализовать

Tags: java, android, json

Помогите , немогу реализовать Json код .
Мне нужно взять данные но немогу понять как ....
можете мне прописать этот код.....

Json лежит в папке assets/json/dannye.json

Вот реализатор класс

```
public class Utility {


public static String getFileContent(Context context) throws IOException {

    InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open("json/dannye.json");

    StringBuilder rawContentBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    inputStream.read(buffer);

    do {
        String chunk = new String(buffer);
        rawContentBuilder.append(chunk);
    } while (inputStream.read(buffer) > 0);

    return rawContentBuilder.toString();
  }
}
```

А вот так я его беру из класса Фрагмент

```
private List<Dannye> initData() {


    try {

        String rawJson = Utility.getFileContent(getContext());
        JSONObject(rawJson).getJSONArray(groupName);
        JSONArray group = new JSONObject(rawJson).getJSONArray("d_1_18");

        Log.e(TAG, "initializeHeroes: " + group);

        list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < group.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject hero = group.getJSONObject(i);


            String hour = hero.getString("hour");
            String lesson = hero.getString("lesson");
            String spes = hero.getString("spes");
            String aut = hero.getString("aut");

            Dannye dannye = new Dannye(hour, lesson, spes, aut);
            list.add(dannye);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("NO bATTLE.JSON!!!");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        System.out.println("JSON MALFoRMEEEED!!");
    }

    return list;

   }
```

Как мне прописать код чтоб взять данные у меня ошибка NullpointExeption

Вот собственно Json

```
  {
   "d_1_18": {

    "Monday": [{
        "hour": "08:00",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    },{
        "hour": "09:30",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    },{
        "hour": "11:00",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    },{
        "hour": "12:30",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    },{
        "hour": "14:00",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    },{
        "hour": "15:30",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    },{
        "hour": "17:00",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    }],

    "Tuesday": [{
        "hour": "08:00",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    },{
        "hour": "09:30",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    },{
        "hour": "11:00",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    },{
        "hour": "12:30",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    },{
        "hour": "14:00",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    },{
        "hour": "15:30",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    },{
        "hour": "17:00",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    }]
    },

     "d_2_18": {

    "Monday": [{
        "hour": "08:00",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    },{
        "hour": "09:30",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    },{
        "hour": "11:00",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    },{
        "hour": "12:30",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    },{
        "hour": "14:00",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    },{
        "hour": "15:30",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    },{
        "hour": "17:00",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    }],

    "Tuesday": [{
        "hour": "08:00",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    },{
        "hour": "09:30",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    },{
        "hour": "11:00",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    },{
        "hour": "12:30",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    },{
        "hour": "14:00",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    },{
        "hour": "15:30",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    },{
        "hour": "17:00",
        "lesson": "Informatika",
        "spes": "prog",
        "aut": "105"
    }]
}
```

}

Comment: Пожалуйста помогите!

Comment: Может потому что _Json лежит в папке assets/ **java** /dannye.json_ , а открываете `context.getAssets().open("` **json** `/dannye.json");`?

Comment: код правильный и путь тоже ..... я не могу понять как взять через код  JSONArray group = new JSONObject(rawJson).getJSONArray("d_1_18"); дальше не знаю учу смотрю уроки но все равно немогу понять

Comment: Как же правильный - если файл лежит в папке _java_ , а открываете из папки _json_ ? Ну ладно, тогда на какую строку указывает ошибка?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.nurkan.iip.Adapter.DAdapter.getItemCount(DAdapter.java:48)

Comment: путь правильный  assets/json/dannye.json

Comment: пересмотрел еще раз там все правильно

Answer (score 2):

`d_1_18` - у Вас объект (фигурные скобки`{}`), а массив `Monday` (угловые`[]`), значит код должен быть таким:

```
JSONArray group = new JSONObject(rawJson).getJSONObject("d_1_18").getJSONArray("Monday");
```

**P.S.** Чтобы не получать NPE в адаптере лучше создавать пустой список сразу при объявлении, а потом наполнять данными.

Comment: Спасибо! сработало ))

Comment: @Nurkan если ответ наиболее подходящий, отметь его галочкой слева от ответа